# iOS 10 public beta infinite loop

Tags: iphone, ios

So I tried signing up for Apple beta program where I use Safari on my iPhone 6 and go to beta.apple.com and tap sign up. I'm then taken to the login page, and just after that to the legal page where I accept the terms of Apple beta program. This is where it falls apart and instead of redirection to the beta profile download page I get redirected back to beta welcome page where I can sign up again, accept the agreement again and than be sent right back to welcome page, thus creating an infinite loop.

Things I tried:

1. Deleting old iOS 9 beta profile and rebooting
2. Reverting back to non beta iOS 9.3.2
3. Restoring my iPhone to factory defaults
4. Leaving and signing back up for beta
5. Trying beta.apple.com/profile directly, but again result is an infinite loop
6. Searching Apple and Apple oriented sites for a solution
7. Sacrificing a goat

Basically nothing works for me, and visiting beta.apple.com on any browser, desktop or mobile is resulting in the same annoying behavior.

Comment: _Basically nothing works for me, and visiting beta.apple.com on any browser, desktop or mobile is resulting in the same annoying behavior._ You tried to sign up on a Desktop computer as well?

Comment: Yes, just to see is doing the same thing - and it is. It can't figure out it's not iOS device like it did for iOS 9 public beta last year.

Comment: Can you try throwing away any burnt cookies?

Comment: Did you try to clear your cookies?

Comment: No cookies or any data is there after factory reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.. I really don't know how I fixed it because it was with iOS 9 public beta. I'm on iOS now, and here is the exact link for the beta profile. Also, just make sure you are enrolled in the program with apple or you won't be able to use feedback assistant.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B92o0HIZOVnQcWNZYXc1WktsNWM

Comment: Thanks but this od not working, "rid=..." part is a unique and required request id so it just pops an error.

Comment: Using that link I am actually able to download the actual profile on to my computer. I'll upload it to google drive and put the link here.

Comment: I added the link to my answer for you

Comment: Ok, it looks like it's working. Still says signed by Apple, it installed and requested the update to public beta 1.

Comment: Good. It should work normally